# Vaping Alcohol - fad or here to stay?

Tags: taste, health, hangover

Just recently I discovered that not only can I vape in stead of smoking, but I can also vape instead of drinking.  What's vaping alcohol all about?  Well, you put a shot of spirits into an orb, which sits over a small candle (tea-light), and then through a glass or metal straw inhale the results.([check it out here with buzzfeed](https://www.buzzfeed.com/nicolenguyen/we-tried-vaping-alcohol-and-it-was-definitely-something?utm_term=.cmNBppdOp#.ibzzeegYe))

This is what the Vaportini looks like - credit Vaportini

[image]

I understand that the alcohol bypasses the liver stage and just goes straight to your head and lungs.  So, none of that 'oops, I've drunk too much - excuse me whilst I visit the bathroom' nonsense, with this method you apparently don't get to expell what your body can't handle.

With all this in mind, is there a limit (average) that can be vaped without doing myself some serious brain damage?  What also is the effect on the lungs?  Is this just another fad or is this the future?

Comment: Alcohol is metabolized in the liver where it's broken down so no matter how you ingest your alcohol (smoking, eating, vaping, intravenous) it still has to go through your liver. It's a well known fact that the purer the alcohol the smaller the hangover. See Grant and Tory on Mythbusters when they get drunk on beer then vodka and test the strength of their hangovers. The vodka hangover is clearly not as bad.

Comment: Could the down voter please explain their vote for me.

Comment: I did not down vote your question, but it does seem a little "opinion based." What sources can we use to determine if this is a "fad or here to stay?" Personally only time will tell.

Comment: @Ken Graham.  Yup not a prob as you would say you were the down voter.  It  was something I came across and thought, hey, here's a new idea.  As you say only time will tell, personally, I think pubs with liquid are here to stay.

Comment: I agree that any answers to whether or not vaping alcohol is a fad would be based largely on conjecture and should be edited out. However, that was a small part of the question. The safe use of, and the effect on the lungs, are excellent questions. I'd say that of course any answers posted online should be taken with a dose of skepticism and always ask a real doctor. I also think you'll get better answers on Health SE. But this question deserves to stay open.

Comment: Yea if you could edit the question to be more clearly less opinion based that would be better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Limit: So, I would speculate that if you're "vaping" the same quantity of alcohol as you might instead drink, then you're facing the same risk. It's the same as drinking alcohol - the risk is cumulative and hard to define - it really [depends](https://www.betterhealth.vic.gov.au/health/conditionsandtreatments/alcohol-related-brain-impairment) on **how much** you drink and **how often**.

Effect on lungs: Frankly this is hard to say, as I am quite confident there have been no large scale (AKA reputable) studies (nor can I find any) performed on the effect of vaping alcohol on lung tissues. I would *expect* the effects to be minimal, but then again, personally, I'd probably still just stick to drinking my alcohol.

I can't provide any scientific basis to this, but I am thoroughly confident that vaping is simply a fad or novelty to enjoy - think of the increased costs and lack of accessibility compared to just drinking alcohol - you simply need a bottle of beer and a fridge, or a bottle of spirits and a glass versus a specialised glass, tea candle, vapour catching vessel and a **glass or metal straw** (seriously, who keeps one of them around?).